# $a\geq 0, b\geq 0, c \geq 0$ and $a\leq b+c$, then there exists $x\geq 0 $ and $y\geq 0$ such that $x+y=a$, $x\leq b$ and $y \leq c $.

Tags: real-analysis

For $a,b,c$ be non-negative reals such that $a\leq b+c$. Then prove that there exists non-negative reals $x$ and $y$ such that $x+y=a$, $x\leq b$ and $y \leq$ c.

Comment: I have taken cases where $b$ and $c$ are lower than $a$, both greater than $a$ and one on each side. No idea to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

If either $b\geq a$ or $c\geq a$, then $0+a=a$ works. If both $b$ and $c$ are smaller than $a$, then see that $a=b+(a-b)$, and $x=b\leq b$ and $0\leq y=a-b\leq c$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arthur. Its done.